# Outlook 2010 - how to remove "You forwarded this message on" line in email with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

Does anyone know if there is a property associated with the grey message that appears under the Sender's name in a forwarded email? On Exchange it is "You forwarded this message on mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM" next to a small blue icon with an "i" in it.

I have not been able to identify the property in the Object Reference.

i would like to turn this off after forwarding an email in a VBA routine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any properties for that.

But you can try to read the MAPI property PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED (0x10810003) to detect the last action made with the Outlook item. I suppose the information text is based on that property value.

Answer (score 0):

PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"`) determines the action kind (forward/reply/reply all) and `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME` (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040")` determines the time. You can delete these properties using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.DeleteProperty`.

Take a look at the properties in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IMessage button).